# Character corruption while xmlParsing

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsxml

I am calling a webservice which returns xml data. Now when I receive the xml data, it is all distorted. all the escape characters like "<", ">" and " ' " are converted to html format

i.e. ≶ > and ".

So now, the parser is not able to recognize the tags.

This is my response from webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetCustomerInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="http://qa2.alliancetek.com/phpwebservice">
<return xsi:type="xsd:string">
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;customer&gt;&lt;id&gt;1&lt;/id&gt;&lt;customername&gt;Hitesh&lt;/customername&gt;&lt;phonenumber&gt;98989898&lt;/phonenumber&gt;&lt;/customer&gt;
</return>
</ns1:GetCustomerInfoResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The content between the return tags are xml data. When I copied the xml data into a NSMutableString variable, and performed replace characters operation, then also it didn't change.

Comment: i have been able to reconstruct the xml data, by copying the nsdata variable into string and replacing the escape characters in the string and assigning the string back to nsdata. But the problem is when the xml parser starts parsing the tags, it gets stuck right where i replaced the tags, it doesnt go at all. so wat do i do now

Comment: it seems that the nsdata isnt working properly. can anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace occurences of ≶ &tg; and " with a whitespace.